# when i was compile, i passed configure but encounter errors when i was 'making'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, github, gnu-make, libtool

I use ./configure and make to compile Dragon from Github on Ubuntu. i passed my configure process even though there is a warning for DarkSUSY which is optional according to the installation document. and i just run 'make' process. after some time, i encounter an error here is my error

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/media/rainman/d/DM/DRAGON'
Making all in cparamlib
make[2]: Entering directory '/media/rainman/d/DM/DRAGON/cparamlib'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/media/rainman/d/DM/DRAGON/cparamlib'
make[2]: Entering directory '/media/rainman/d/DM/DRAGON'
/bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=F77   --mode=compile  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I/media/rainman/d/DM/DRAGON/include -I/media/rainman/d/DM/DRAGON/cparamlib -DTIXML_USE_STL -I/media/rainman/d/DM/gsl/scalar/include -I/media/rainman/d/DM/cfitsio/scalar//include   -c -o dmspec.lo dmspec.F
Usage: /media/rainman/d/DM/DRAGON/libtool [OPTION]... [MODE-ARG]..
``Try 'libtool --help' for more information.
libtool:   error: unrecognised option: '-DHAVE_CONFIG_H'
Makefile:756: recipe for target 'dmspec.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [dmspec.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/media/rainman/d/DM/DRAGON'
Makefile:806: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/rainman/d/DM/DRAGON'
Makefile:573: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

on the other computer i successfully pass 'make' while did the same thing but failed. i do not know how to deal with this. could anyone help me out? thanks

Comment: This seems like a bug in the Dragon environment.  Or maybe you have a too new or too old version of libtool on your system (what version of Ubuntu are you using?)  In any event this is an issue you should probably raise with the Dragon developers, maybe in their Github Issues or similar.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu12.1,i also tried two versions.of Dragon,however,.it still report the same error,could it be something wrong with my libtool,that i need to.reinstall it?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 12.1.  If you mean Ubuntu 12.10, that version has been unsupported for almost 3 years now.  I recommend you upgrade to a supported version of Ubuntu, in general.  There's no newer version of libtool released as a package for such an old version of Ubuntu.  You could try installing a newer libtool from source instead of a package.  I can't say whether or not that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The most relevant part of the error you recieved is

```
libtool:   error: unrecognised option: '-DHAVE_CONFIG_H'
```

This error looks similar to that encountered in [Error installing PCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866445/error-installing-pcre), which was due to not having the 'g++' c++ compiler installed.

**Try installing build-essential** (`apt-get install build-essential`) which should ensure you have the bare minimum necessary installed to compile most software, including g++.

Comment: i've tried your suggestion,but it seems does not work since there is nothing to be upgraded when i use apt-get install build-essential.could there be any other possible reasons cause the problem?